# What is common workflow between Blender modeler and unity programmer?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, game-development

I am Unity programmer and I work with Blender 3d modeler.
We are a team to make a Unity 3d game.

This is our current workflow.

1. Modeler make 3d models in blender.
2. Modeler gives me fbx files and separate texture image files.
3. I import fbx files to unity and manually apply texture files and adjust detail value about materials and textures asking him about visual details to make sure.

I feel this is wrong that I (programmer) have to rework all of the visual details.
How do other modelers and programmers co-work in game company or game team?

Comment: Our workflow is something as follows, the artist makes all the necessary art in my case 3D models, and set everything up in a Unity scene in an environment with everything lightning Materials etc, and then they export that scene and all I have to do is to import the scene.

Comment: But that would raise another issue or organizing all of your assets until and unless you have a fixed/same directory structure, it is going to mess things up in your project. and I guess you can assume where this could lead.

Comment: _"I feel this is wrong that I (programmer) have to rework all of the visual details"_ - depends on how big your game shop is.  The bigger they are the less likely programmers are responsible for _any_ form of artwork.   That's why Perforce source control has a separate app _just for the artists_ in addition to P4V.  It all comes down to workflows and artists and programmers have different needs.

Answer (score 1):

The proper workflow from blender to Unity would be: (See this [link](https://youtu.be/8khJoTdoOvY))

1. Verify the Licensing for the 3D Model
2. Arrange Your File
3. Choose an Appropriate Name for the Asset and Materials/Textures
4. Review the Number of Tris and Vertices (Utilize the Decimate modifier if optimization is necessary)
5. Implement All Modifiers
6. Merge Meshes
7. Ensure Proper Scale
8. Establish Correct Location in Coordinates (Rectify Coordinate System)
9. Apply All Transformations
10. Configure Origin to Geometry
11. Consolidate Materials by baking into a unified texture
    12 Address any Potential Issues
12. Develop Levels of Detail (LOD)
13. Confirm Face Orientation